# How Visualize variable data from jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a simple jQuery code that fetches specific data from an html Table i need to display this data in a pie chart

this is the jQuery code

`

```
function no(){

     var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j;
     filter = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();

    table = document.getElementById("table1");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
      const tdArray = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      for (var j = 0; j < tdArray.length; j++) {
        const cellValue = tdArray[j];
        if (cellValue && cellValue.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          break;
        }
  
      }
  
  
    }
  
      var update = $('table tr:contains(Update):visible').length;
      update = "Update occurnces: " + update
      document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = update;

      var HardDelete= $('#table1').find('tr:contains(HardDelete):visible').length;
      

      var SoftDelete = $('table tr:contains(SoftDelete):visible').length;
       var Create = $('table tr:contains(Create):visible').length;
      Create = "Create occurnces: " + Create
      document.getElementById("Create").innerHTML = Create;
    

      var SoftHDelete = $('table tr:contains(SoftDelete):visible,tr:contains(HardDelete):visible').length;
      SoftHDelete = "Soft And Hard Delete occurnces: " + SoftHDelete +  " <br> " +"<br>" + SoftDelete +": "+ " is SoftDeleted And " + " ' " + HardDelete + " ' " + " HardDeleted ";
      document.getElementById("demosh").innerHTML = SoftHDelete;


      var Copy = $('table tr:contains(Copy):visible').length;
      Copy = "Copy occurnces: " + Copy
      document.getElementById("Copy").innerHTML = Copy;
      
      var MoveToDeletedItems = $('table tr:contains(MoveToDeletedItems):visible').length;
      MoveToDeletedItems = "MoveToDeletedItems occurnces: " + MoveToDeletedItems
      document.getElementById("MoveToDeletedItems").innerHTML = MoveToDeletedItems;

      var Move = $('table tr:contains(Move):visible').length;
      Move = "Move occurnces: " + Move
      document.getElementById("Move").innerHTML = Move;

    }
  </script>
```

`

I want to visulize the VAR Values.

I tried using many sample codes but I don't know how get the data from the query instead of a fixed values.

Comment: Try posting a simplified example, make it well-formatted, and explain exactly what do you want to do with it because it's not clear. A pie chart isn't a built-in feature

Comment: Can you post the sample data which you want to be visualised in a pie chart ? There are many tools like d3.js etc.

Comment: i want these values which are from a table:

var SoftDelete = $('table tr:contains(SoftDelete):visible').length;

to be Visualized in a chart

Answer (score 0):

One approach with `CSS`: use `conic-gradient`

```js
const data = [
  10,
  20,
  30,
  15,
  25,
]

const colors = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#f0f000", "#f000f0"]

const sumArr = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
const normalizeVal = (sum) => (val) => (val / sum) * 360
const normalizeArr = (arr) => arr.map(normalizeVal(sumArr(arr)))

const getDegs = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    a.degs = [...a.degs, [a.curr, a.curr + c]]
    a.curr += c
    return a
  }, {
    curr: 0,
    degs: []
  }).degs
}

const getDegVal = (val) => `${val}deg`
const getDegValString = (colors) => ([start, end], i) => [colors[i], getDegVal(start), getDegVal(end)].join(" ")

const getConicalCss = (colors) => (arr) => "conic-gradient(" + arr.map(getDegValString(colors)).join(", ") + ")"

$(".donut").css("background", getConicalCss(colors)(getDegs(normalizeArr(data))))
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.donut {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.donut::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="donut"></div>
</div>
```